# Реферальная система без регистарции

Tags: mysqli, php

Например человек зашел на страницу (не какой регистрации на сайте нет) для него сгенерировалась реф. ссылка, и отображается рядом сколько он человек пригласил. 
Если кто-то перешел по его ссылке то ему защиталось +1 в приглашенные, и если этот пользователь еще раз перешел по ссылке то уже не зачитывается переход. Уже мучаюсь около двух дней не могу сделать.

Объясните как сделать это ? без кода, если с кодом то большое спасибо (но это наглость)

Пример: http://steam.astu-search.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день Дмитрий!

Поскольку регистрации на сайте нет, а разделить пользователя А от пользователя Б всё же надо (иначе как генерировать им разные ссылки и учитывать кто по их ссылкам ходил) то это происходит через куки, ведь, как говорил поэт, нет ничего нового в подлунном мире.
В том что это печенька легко убедиться глядя сюда:

[image]

Итак, зашел пользователь, проверили есть ли у него уже печенька регистрации или нет

1. **Если нет** - сгенерировали печеньку, записали в неё уникальный
   ключ. Для всех рефералов пользователя используем этот ключ, показываем сколько людей заходило по его рефералам.
2. **Если есть** - считали печеньку, это наш парень, далее всё как в п.1

Думаю с "регистрацией" такого рода всё понятно. Как её плюсы так и минусы.

Далее, зашел пользователь по рефералу. Тут уже интереснее, и зависит от вашей задачи. В основе своей задача проста - взять ключ (из реферала) и увеличить на 1 значение счетчика владельца этого ключа при посещении **уникального** пользователя. Так что в этой части задачи самое сложное - оценить уникален ли пользователь. Это может быть и IP или строка Agent браузера или хеш, состоящий из расширения экрана, броузера, ОС, IP - это всё на ваше усмотрение и упорство :-)

Надеюсь ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: огромное спасибо :)